# Assign value to variable - Simplify existing code

Tags: javascript

The code is as follows.

```
this.requiredVehicle = order.vehicle
      ? order.vehicle
      : order.required_vehicle_type && order.required_vehicle_type;
```

If vehicle is present in the order, that value should be assigned else if required_vehicle_type is present, it should be assigned.
How to simplify the above code ?

Comment: `??`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: `order.vehicle || order.required_vehicle_type`  or `??`

Comment: You could do `this.requiredVehicle = order.vehicle || order.required_vehicle_type || null`

Comment: @secan The `|| null` is probably superfluous, unless you have specific requirements about the value's type…

Comment: @deceze, yes, you are right;  it is not strictly necessary but, in a case like this, I always tend to explicitly set something to `null` rather than leaving it undefined. If something is `null`, you know "it exists" and someone took it into consideration and explicitly decided it should have no value; if it is `undefined` you always wonder if it exist and whether it is `undefined` because of an error or because of an explicit choice.